# Cassandra - Read Performance Variation

Tags: performance, cassandra

I have written 6 Million records to a column family in Cassandra (3 Nodes,2 GB Heap per node).

Now, when I read the same 6 million records sequentially, I find a huge variation in the read performance(reads/sec).

I have attached the graph. Any help is appreciated.

[image: Cassandra - Read performance graph]

Answer (score 0):

There can be different causes. More information about your case is needed. Below I've put some recommendations of what you can do:

1. If you use cassandra 2.0 You can get breakdown of timings for each query by layers involved.
   In sqlsh tool it can be turned on by "TRACING ON" command. Same thing can be done for Cassandra Java driver to get more details. So using this you can figure out the layer where most of the time is consumed. (e.g. it might be you have some network issues)
2. Look at Cassandra logs and try to juxtapose their entries with your performance fluctuations
3. Create histogram of your column family and analyze it
   ./nodetool -h  cfhistograms  
   (Here you can find some explanation on histograms: http://narendrasharma.blogspot.com/2011/04/cassandra-07x-understanding-output-of.html)
4. Observe Java Garbage collector logs (https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/01/useful-jvm-flags-part-8-gc-logging/)

hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the reply . Can you explain how read related to the Os level file caching ?